# rails deeply nested form_for not able to save twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, form-for, nested-form-for

I have a form where teams can register for a tournament. The form saves & routes as expected when I first save the form, however if I return to the root_path & repeat the process of registering a team, the form doesn't save at all (clicking on the "Submit" button does nothing).

My feeling is that something is hanging around from the original save that is stopping a new one from happening, but I'm not able to put my finger on what it is. Code is below, hope it is sufficient.

(routes.rb)

```
root 'tournaments#index'
  resources :tournaments do
    resources :teams do
      resources :players, :only => [:new, :create]
    end
  end
```

(models)

```
class Tournament < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teams
  has_many :players, :through => :teams

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :players  
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tournament, required: false
  has_many :players

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :players
end

class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team, required: false
  has_one :tournament, :through => :team
end
```

(tournaments_controller.rb)

```
  def index
    @tournaments = Tournament.all
  end

  def show
    @tournament = Tournament.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @tournament = Tournament.new
  end

  def create
      @tournament = Tournament.new(tournament_params)
      if @tournament.save
      flash[:notice] = "#{@tournament.name} saved."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end


  private

  def tournament_params
    params.require(:tournament).permit(:name, :deadline, :divisions, :info, :payment, :tournament_date, team_attributes: [:name, :division, :contact_email, :contact_name])
  end
```

(teams_controller.rb)

```
    def create
        @team = Team.new(team_params)
        if @team.save
          flash[:notice] = "Team Registered."
          redirect_to tournament_team_path(params[:tournament_id], @team.id)
        else
          redirect_to new_tournament_team_path(params[:tournament_id])
        end     
    end

    def new
        @tournament = Tournament.find_by_id(params[:tournament_id])
        @team = Team.new
        8.times do
          @team.players.build
        end
    end

    def show
    @tournament = Tournament.find(params[:tournament_id])
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    end


    private

  def team_params
    params.require(:team).permit(:name, :tournament_id, :division, :contact_name, :contact_email, players_attributes: [ :name, :gender, :referee ])
  end
```

Entry link from tournaments#show page to the teams#new action (this works ... as far as that it links to the correct page)

```
<%= link_to(new_tournament_team_path(params[:id])) do %><div class="rounded_btn"><h3>Register Team</h3></div><% end %>
```

(teams/new.html.erb) - this is the form that doesn't work. I should use partials, but I'd like to get it working to start.

```
<main class="long_page">
    <h1 class="tournament_name"><%= @tournament.name %></h1>
    <h3 class="tournament_name">Team Registration</h3>
<section style="align-items: baseline;">
    <div class="rounded_box">
        <%= form_for [@tournament, @team] do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :tournament_id, :value => @tournament.id %>
            <div>
             <p>
                <%= f.label :division, "Division: " %>
                <%= f.select :division, options_for_select([["Mixed", "mixed"], ["Mens", "mens"]]) %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <%= f.text_field :name, required: '' %>
                <label alt='Team Name' placeholder='Team Name'></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <%= f.text_field :contact_name, required: '' %>
                <label alt='Contact Person' placeholder='Contact Person'></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <%= f.text_field :contact_email, required: '' %>
                <label alt='Contact Email' placeholder='Contact Email'></label>
            </p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            <%= f.fields_for :players do |builder| %>
                <div>
                   <%= builder.text_field :name, required: '' %>
                   <%= builder.select :gender, options_for_select([["Male", "male"], ["Female", "female"]]) %>
                   <%= builder.select :referee, options_for_select([["No", "no"], ["Yes", "yes"]]) %>

                </div>
            <% end %>

            </div>
            <div class="btn_holder">
            <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit Team', :class => 'rounded_btn' %>
</p></div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</section>
```

This generates the following HTML output:

```
<body>
    <container>
      <header class="header" id="header">
    <a href="/"><img alt="Taipei Touch Association Logo" src="/assets/taipei_touch_logo_faded-4bbdd185e462f4d8af3b2d25f221f27f4ae479c8adfa4701b8c3f03e9e31b36c.svg"></a>
    <span class="header_span">
        <h4>Taipei Touch Association</h4>
        <h3>Tournament Management System</h3>
    </span>
</header>
    <main class="long_page">
    <h1 class="tournament_name">Dummy Tournament</h1>
    <h3 class="tournament_name">Team Registration</h3>
<section style="align-items: baseline;">
    <div class="rounded_box">
        <form class="new_team" id="new_team" action="/tournaments/1/teams" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="+CtsL2QcMjj1703iGPpwgs8vYu7TWJfWt9jTUgCYTMaFE9JdvYIMJqdb87z4vKuDzUgb8RO96Mdvk5fW/uJUSw==">
        <input value="1" type="hidden" name="team[tournament_id]" id="team_tournament_id">
            <div>
             <p>
                <label for="team_division">Division: </label>
                <select name="team[division]" id="team_division"><option value="mixed">Mixed</option>
<option value="mens">Mens</option></select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input required="required" type="text" name="team[name]" id="team_name">
                <label alt="Team Name" placeholder="Team Name"></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input required="required" type="text" name="team[contact_name]" id="team_contact_name">
                <label alt="Contact Person" placeholder="Contact Person"></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input required="required" type="text" name="team[contact_email]" id="team_contact_email">
                <label alt="Contact Email" placeholder="Contact Email"></label>
            </p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>


                <div>
                   <input required="required" type="text" name="team[players_attributes][0][name]" id="team_players_attributes_0_name">
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][0][gender]" id="team_players_attributes_0_gender"><option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option></select>
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][0][referee]" id="team_players_attributes_0_referee"><option value="no">No</option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option></select>

                </div>

                <div>
                   <input required="required" type="text" name="team[players_attributes][1][name]" id="team_players_attributes_1_name">
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][1][gender]" id="team_players_attributes_1_gender"><option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option></select>
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][1][referee]" id="team_players_attributes_1_referee"><option value="no">No</option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option></select>

                </div>

                <div>
                   <input required="required" type="text" name="team[players_attributes][2][name]" id="team_players_attributes_2_name">
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][2][gender]" id="team_players_attributes_2_gender"><option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option></select>
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][2][referee]" id="team_players_attributes_2_referee"><option value="no">No</option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option></select>

                </div>

                <div>
                   <input required="required" type="text" name="team[players_attributes][3][name]" id="team_players_attributes_3_name">
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][3][gender]" id="team_players_attributes_3_gender"><option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option></select>
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][3][referee]" id="team_players_attributes_3_referee"><option value="no">No</option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option></select>

                </div>

                <div>
                   <input required="required" type="text" name="team[players_attributes][4][name]" id="team_players_attributes_4_name">
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][4][gender]" id="team_players_attributes_4_gender"><option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option></select>
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][4][referee]" id="team_players_attributes_4_referee"><option value="no">No</option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option></select>

                </div>

                <div>
                   <input required="required" type="text" name="team[players_attributes][5][name]" id="team_players_attributes_5_name">
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][5][gender]" id="team_players_attributes_5_gender"><option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option></select>
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][5][referee]" id="team_players_attributes_5_referee"><option value="no">No</option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option></select>

                </div>

                <div>
                   <input required="required" type="text" name="team[players_attributes][6][name]" id="team_players_attributes_6_name">
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][6][gender]" id="team_players_attributes_6_gender"><option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option></select>
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][6][referee]" id="team_players_attributes_6_referee"><option value="no">No</option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option></select>

                </div>

                <div>
                   <input required="required" type="text" name="team[players_attributes][7][name]" id="team_players_attributes_7_name">
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][7][gender]" id="team_players_attributes_7_gender"><option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option></select>
                   <select name="team[players_attributes][7][referee]" id="team_players_attributes_7_referee"><option value="no">No</option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option></select>

                </div>

            </form></div>
            <div class="btn_holder">
            <p>
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit Team" class="rounded_btn" data-disable-with="Submit Team">
</p></div>

</section>
    </main>
    </container>




</body>
```

Note: This problem persists even when using the nested_forms gem.

Comment: If it's not an AJAX form (which it isn't) then the only thing that could be stopping a submit button from doing it's action is an HTML syntax error. When you go back to the page and it doesnt' work, right click, inspect submit button element, and paste the element code and 2 of its 3 parents.

Comment: @RichardAE Here's the code around the submit button & the <form> code as well  
 `<form class="new_team" id="new_team" action="/tournaments/1/teams" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">`
`<div class="btn_holder">
         <p>
 <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit Team" class="rounded_btn" data-disable-with="Submit Team">
    </p></div> `

Comment: Can you edit your question and that HTML code so it's formatted properly?

Comment: I updated my original answer with the client-side html that's generated. Is that what you meant @RichardAE

Comment: Updated: I deleted `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` from my /views/application.erb.html file & now the funtion seems to work.

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply. Glad you got it sorted, Turbolinks means all forms go through Javascript which would explain it. I will need to remember that for questions like this in future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` from my /views/application.erb.html file & now the funtion seems to work.